# Getting error NoClassDefFoundError when using embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm trying use embedded Tomcat in my java web app within Eclipse maven project. But when I run

```
mvn clean compile;
mvn package;
java -jar target\employees-app-1.0.jar
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat
```

My pom.xml file contains the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

and following plugins:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the `tomcat.version` property value?

Comment: tomcat version is 10.1.18.